# Using "?:" to emulate short-circuit evaluation

Tags: java, short-circuiting

How would one be able to emulate `foo() || bar()` and `foo() && bar()` using short-circuiting and the `?:` operator?

I'm a student and have never used the `?:` operator and would like to try. After doing some Googling I've found out that it's essentially:

`Condition ? (things to do if true) : (things to do if false);`

Would this be possible to achieve without using `&&` and `||`? I'm trying to get a grip on short-circuiting, as I'm very new to it and finals are coming up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `foo()` and `bar()` both return `boolean`, then

```
foo() || bar()
```

is the same as

```
foo() ? true : bar();
```

because `foo()` is evaluated first, and `bar()` only needs to be evaluated if `foo()` is false.

Likewise,

```
foo() && bar()
```

is the same as

```
foo() ? bar() : false;
```

`foo()` is evaluated first, and `bar()` only needs to be evaluated if `foo()` is true.